# Finding head section of HTML in Emeditor

Tags: emeditor

I'm trying to use EmEditor to do some find and replace on HTML using regex. I know that Regex is not generally suitable for HTML parsing but I believe it will work for my limited requirement. I can't get it to do some fairly simple finds. e.g. find the head section and remove it.  I've tried several different syntaxes e.g. `<head.*?>(.|\n)*?</head>` also simpler ones where there are no attributes e.g. `<head>.*?</head>`.  None work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try a non-zero value to the **Additional Lines to Search for Regular Expressions** text box in the **Advanced** dialog box (Click the **Advanced** button in the **Find** dialog box) if you need to search for multi-line strings.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to confirm that this worked before going on holiday.  Thanks